# Remove duplicate records from mysql table

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I am trying to delete some duplicate records from mysql table but it was not working.[image]

I am taking help of https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-delete-duplicate-records

If I will try with example database which is given example it was working fine.

But in my table it was not working.

```
DELETE  S1 FROM employee_attendance AS S1 INNER JOIN employee_attendance AS S2 WHERE S1.DbKey < S2.DbKey AND S1.DivisionDbKey = S2.DivisionDbKey AND S1.Date = S2.Date AND S1.Month = S2.Month AND S1.FinancialYearDbKey = S2.FinancialYearDbKey AND S1.EmployeeDbKey = S2.EmployeeDbKey AND S1.Attendance = S2.Attendance  AND S1.InTime = S2.InTime  AND S1.OutTime = S2.OutTime AND S1.EmployeeDbKey = 6798 AND S1.Month = '05' AND S1.FinancialYearDbKey = 5;
```

I am getting error

#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

I have tried with another example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-query-to-delete-duplicate-rows/

```
DELETE FROM employee_attendance WHERE DbKey NOT IN (SELECT MAX(DbKey) FROM employee_attendance WHERE EmployeeDbKey = 6798 AND Month = '05' AND FinancialYearDbKey = '5' GROUP BY DivisionDbKey,Date,Month,FinancialYearDbKey,EmployeeDbKey,Attendance,InTime,OutTime)
```

I am getting same error.

#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Any suggestion will be appriciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you make the meaning of `duplicate records` explicit with respect to your table? I don't see any duplicate record in your table as long as `DbKey` seems to be unique for all your records.

Comment: DbKey is primary key with auto increment. Check 9th date and 20th date same data for all columns  except DbKey column.

Comment: What version on MySQL? MySQL version 8 introduces `row_number() over()` which makes this quite simple to solve. Please always tell us the dbms version you use.

Comment: Please don't show us an image of your data, use a text table instead. This allows us to build a table and demonstrate our proposed solution. This is not feasible with images of data.  Imagine us providing images of sql as the solution - that would be frustrating I suspect.

Comment: I am using Server version: 10.4.14-MariaDB. Thank you @Paul Maxwell . My problem was resolved. In this case If I am trying with 100 records my query was working fine. When I am tring with realtable it was not working. my table having nearly 1M. records so I can't give the text table.

Comment: I changed the tag to suit the db and version you do use. Maria-db does support `row_number() over()` so I'm not sure why you would pursue a more complex approach.  Finally, supply of **sample** does not require *nearly 1m* rows, but images of sample data should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally think this is a bad practice. You should instead make a (empty) duplicate of the table `employee_attendance` then define a `UNIQUE KEY` on that new table that will prevent duplicate entries.

Consider these steps:

1. Create a duplicate table:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_attendance_new LIKE employee_attendance;
```

2. Add `UNIQUE INDEX` - now, this is just a simple example. You can add or reduce columns to the unique index but make sure that you drop the existing unique index first then only you re-create:

```
ALTER TABLE employee_attendance_new 
      ADD UNIQUE INDEX unq_idx(EmployeeDbKey, date, InTime, OutTime);
```

3. Insert the data into the new table using `INSERT IGNORE..`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO employee_attendance_new 
 SELECT * FROM employee_attendance;
```

4. Check and compare both table. If you're satisfied with the result, rename those tables:

```
RENAME TABLE employee_attendance TO employee_attendance_old;
RENAME TABLE employee_attendance_new TO employee_attendance;
```

5. Now you have the new table with no duplicates and the old table for reference or in case there are some data you need from it.

[Fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1fd1da6c76df964ee649fc0a12464c1b)

Comment: Thank you @FanoFN. to give your valuable times and solutions.